# Como hago para crear una busqueda de un array por marca en este caso y subirla a html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, javascript-objeto, busqueda

Quiero hacer un buscador de estos autos, por marca.
Hice un formulario por html y cuando aprete el boton de busqueda que aparezcan todos los autos de la misma marca o en un div o li me da lo mismo.
Y no se como hacerlo. Perdon si alguien podria ayudarme. Muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leerlo.

```
   const autos = [
    {   
        marca: 'BMW',
        modelo: 'Serie 3',
        year: 2020,
        precio: 3000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Blanco',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Audi',
        modelo: 'A4',
        year: 2020,
        precio: 4000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Negro',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Ford',
        modelo: 'Mustang',
        year: 2015,
        precio: 2000000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Blanco',
    },
    {
        marca: 'Audi',
        modelo: 'A6',
        year: 2020,
        precio: 3500000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Negro',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'BMW',
        modelo: 'Serie 5',
        year: 2016,
        precio: 7000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Rojo',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Mercedes Benz',
        modelo: 'Clase C',
        year: 2015,
        precio: 2500000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Blanco',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Chevrolet',
        modelo: 'Camaro',
        year: 2018,
        precio: 6000000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Manual',
        color: 'Rojo',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Ford',
        modelo: 'Mustang',
        year: 2019,
        precio: 8000000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Manual',
        color: 'Rojo',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Dodge',
        modelo: 'Challenger',
        year: 2020,
        precio: 4000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Blanco',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Audi',
        modelo: 'A3',
        year: 2017,
        precio: 1850000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Manual',
        color: 'Negro',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Dodge',
        modelo: 'Challenger',
        year: 2020,
        precio: 2500000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Manual',
        color: 'Rojo',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Mercedes Benz',
        modelo: 'Clase C',
        year: 2018,
        precio: 4500000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Azul',
    },
    {        
        marca: 'BMW',
        modelo: 'Serie 5',
        year: 2019,
        precio: 6000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Blanco',
    },
    {
        marca: 'Ford',
        modelo: 'Mustang',
        year: 2017,
        precio: 6000000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Manual',
        color: 'Negro',
    },
    {
        marca: 'Dodge',
        modelo: 'Challenger',
        year: 2015,
        precio: 3500000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Azul',
    },{
        marca: 'Renault',
        modelo: 'Megane III',
        year: 2017,
        precio: 2500000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automatica',
        color: 'Gris',
    },
    {
        marca: 'BMW',
        modelo: 'Serie 3',
        year: 2018,
        precio: 5000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Blanco',
    },
    {
        marca: 'BMW',
        modelo: 'Serie 5',
        year: 2021,
        precio: 8000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automatica',
        color: 'Negro',
    },
    {
        marca: 'Mercedes Benz',
        modelo: 'Clase C',
        year: 2018,
        precio: 4000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automatica',
        color: 'Blanco',
    },
    {
        marca: 'Renault',
        modelo: 'Clio RS',
        year: 2019,
        precio: 3200000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Manual',
        color: 'Negro',
    },
    {
        marca: 'Audi',
        modelo: 'A4',
        year: 2016,
        precio: 3000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automatica',
        color: 'Azul',
    },
    ];
   

     let miAuto = autos.filter(({marca}) => marca == (ingreso));
```

Lo que quiero hacer es:

```
     <h1>Buscador de Autos Usados</h1>
        <h2>Busqueda de Autos según nombre de la Marca.</h2>
        <h3>"Audi, BMW, Chevrolet, Dodge, Ford, Mercedes Benz, o Renault"</h3>
        <form id="formularioMarcas">
            Selecciona:<br/>
            <select id="buscar">
              <option value="11">Audi</option>
              <option value="22" selected>BMW</option>
              <option value="33">Chevrolet</option>
              <option value="44">Dodge</option>
              <option value="55">Ford</option>
              <option value="66">Mercedes Benz</option>
              <option value="77">Renault</option>
            </select><p/>
           <input type="reset" />
           <input type="submit" id="btnEnviar" name="btnEnviar" value="Busqueda" />
       </form>
```

Cuando ingrese una de las marcas aparezca la lista de todos los autos de esa marca.
Ya no se de que modo hacerlo intente varias y pedi ayuda a un amigo y estoy super bloqueado.
No se que codigo crearle. Ya probe y fallan fallan.
Bueno creo que ya debe ser uno de mis ultimos recursos subirlo a la pagina.
Muchas gracias al que lo lea. Y Mil gracias al que pueda darme algun tipo de solución!
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si solo deseas agregar ese filtro de búsqueda podrías crear una función que renderice la información del los autos y reciba como parametro la marca seleccionada por el usuario. A su vez tambien crear una funcion para manejar el evento "change" de tu select y que ejecute tu función para mostrar la información de los autos según la selección del usuario.

Te dejo un código de como podría hacerlo el cual puedes adaptar para que cumpla tus necesidades.

```js
//Define la lista de autos
const autos = [
    {   
        marca: 'BMW',
        modelo: 'Serie 3',
        year: 2020,
        precio: 3000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Blanco',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Audi',
        modelo: 'A4',
        year: 2020,
        precio: 4000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Negro',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Ford',
        modelo: 'Mustang',
        year: 2015,
        precio: 2000000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Blanco',
    },
    {
        marca: 'Audi',
        modelo: 'A6',
        year: 2020,
        precio: 3500000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Negro',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'BMW',
        modelo: 'Serie 5',
        year: 2016,
        precio: 7000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Rojo',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Mercedes Benz',
        modelo: 'Clase C',
        year: 2015,
        precio: 2500000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Blanco',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Chevrolet',
        modelo: 'Camaro',
        year: 2018,
        precio: 6000000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Manual',
        color: 'Rojo',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Ford',
        modelo: 'Mustang',
        year: 2019,
        precio: 8000000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Manual',
        color: 'Rojo',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Dodge',
        modelo: 'Challenger',
        year: 2020,
        precio: 4000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Blanco',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Audi',
        modelo: 'A3',
        year: 2017,
        precio: 1850000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Manual',
        color: 'Negro',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Dodge',
        modelo: 'Challenger',
        year: 2020,
        precio: 2500000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Manual',
        color: 'Rojo',
    },
    {       
        marca: 'Mercedes Benz',
        modelo: 'Clase C',
        year: 2018,
        precio: 4500000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Azul',
    },
    {        
        marca: 'BMW',
        modelo: 'Serie 5',
        year: 2019,
        precio: 6000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Blanco',
    },
    {
        marca: 'Ford',
        modelo: 'Mustang',
        year: 2017,
        precio: 6000000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Manual',
        color: 'Negro',
    },
    {
        marca: 'Dodge',
        modelo: 'Challenger',
        year: 2015,
        precio: 3500000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Azul',
    },{
        marca: 'Renault',
        modelo: 'Megane III',
        year: 2017,
        precio: 2500000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automatica',
        color: 'Gris',
    },
    {
        marca: 'BMW',
        modelo: 'Serie 3',
        year: 2018,
        precio: 5000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automática',
        color: 'Blanco',
    },
    {
        marca: 'BMW',
        modelo: 'Serie 5',
        year: 2021,
        precio: 8000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automatica',
        color: 'Negro',
    },
    {
        marca: 'Mercedes Benz',
        modelo: 'Clase C',
        year: 2018,
        precio: 4000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automatica',
        color: 'Blanco',
    },
    {
        marca: 'Renault',
        modelo: 'Clio RS',
        year: 2019,
        precio: 3200000,
        puertas: 2,
        transmision: 'Manual',
        color: 'Negro',
    },
    {
        marca: 'Audi',
        modelo: 'A4',
        year: 2016,
        precio: 3000000,
        puertas: 4,
        transmision: 'Automatica',
        color: 'Azul',
    },
];

//Recupera el elemento donde se mostrara la lista de autos
const lista_autos = document.getElementById('lista-autos')

//Funciona para renderizar la lista con la informacion de cada auto la cual puede recibir el parametro de "marca" que por defecto tiene el valor default
function renderListaAutos(marca = "default"){
   //Define un parametro para construir el html a insertar en el documento
   let html_lista_autos = ''
   
   //Recorre la lista de autos
   autos.forEach((auto) => {
   
     //Define un parametro para contruir el html con la informacion del auto
     let html_info_auto = ''
     
     //Si la el parametro "marca" es "default" crea un html con la informacion del auto sin importar la marca, si la marca es distinta solo se crea un html con la informacion del auto si la marca es igual a la seleccionada
     if(marca === "default"){
       html_info_auto = '<div>'+
          '<span>'+auto.modelo+' ' +auto.year+'</span>'+
       '</div>'
     }else{
      if(marca === auto.marca){
        html_info_auto = '<div>'+
           '<span>'+auto.modelo+' ' +auto.year+'</span>'+
       '</div>'
      }
     }
     
     //Añade el html con la informacion del auto al html a insertar en el documento
     html_lista_autos += html_info_auto
   })
   
   //Inserta el html construido con la informacion de los autos al elemento con id "lista-autos" declarado anteriormente
   lista_autos.innerHTML = html_lista_autos
   
}

//Declara una funcion para manejar el evento "change" del elemento select
function onChangeSelect(event){

  //Ejecuta la funcion para renderizar la informacion de los autos con el valor del option seleccionado por el usuario
  renderListaAutos(event.target.value);
}

//Añade la funcion onChangeSelect al evento "change" del elemento select con id "buscar"
document.getElementById('buscar').addEventListener("change", onChangeSelect);

//Ejecuta la funcion para mostrar la informacion de los autos una vez cargado el documento
window.onload = () => {
 renderListaAutos()
}
```

```html
<h1>Buscador de Autos Usados</h1>
        <h2>Busqueda de Autos según nombre de la Marca.</h2>
        <h3>"Audi, BMW, Chevrolet, Dodge, Ford, Mercedes Benz, o Renault"</h3>
        <form id="formularioMarcas">
            Selecciona:<br/>
            <select id="buscar">
              <option value="default" selected>Selecciona una marca</option>

              <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
              <option value="BMW" >BMW</option>
              <option value="Chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
              <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
              <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
              <option value="Mercedes Benz">Mercedes Benz</option>
              <option value="Renault">Renault</option>
            </select><p/>
           <input type="reset" />
           <input type="submit" id="btnEnviar" name="btnEnviar" value="Busqueda" />
       </form>
       
       
       <div id="lista-autos">
          
       </div>
```

Saludos, espero que te haya servido, te adjunto la documentacion de las funciones que considero relevantes de este codigo.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Gracias Diego! Primero que nada muchas gracias por el tiempo que te tomaste para responderme! Un genio! Muchas gracias! Ya lo modifique para que quede un poco a gusto, pero la idea iba por ahi!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Para entender un poco... deseas seleccionar una marca en especifico y que el select de opciones con id "buscar" sea de acuerdo a esa marca de auto que seleccionaste?